# Excel: vba time calculation

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a spreadsheet that is being used to calculate coverage for my department.

One sheet (Sheet1) has the breaks and lunch data with a key for the shifts:

[image: sheet1]

On Sheet2 I have a row of times, and a column with the shift.

I would like to make a UDF or just use a formula if possible to automatically add a 1 or .5 under some conditions. Here is how my row of times is laid out:

[image: sheet2]

I would like to create either a formula or most likely a UDF that will automaticly look up if the current time meets the criteria and put either a 1 or .5 or nothing if the criteria isn't met.

Here is the criteria for a 1:
The time (00:00) has to be in the shift, if the shift ends at (00:30) then (00:30) would have a 0;
If there is a break then the half hour of time should have a .5;
 all lunches are 30 min so if there is a lunch that is on a time (04:30) then (04:30) should be 0 or blank;

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the images correctly, it wouldn't let me because i'm not cool enough (10 rep or more)

Comment: Can you post any code you have tried and what the result has been?

Comment: Dont worry about the image thing, already did it for you.btw I think this is possible withou `UDF`. The `date` and entries in column `Break` , `Lunch` , and `Break2` are same data type? I mean all are time yes?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce thunderblaster. I am still in the middle of working on a first draft for this. I will post it in a moment. My biggest problem has been getting the times in row 1 from strings to times that I can compare in VBA. I can't seem to find any excel vba object that is just used for times. I see a lot of date/time stuff but i'm not sure if this would work for doing comparitive time calculations like (00:30 between 00:00 and 08:30)

Comment: @L42, Not time, if you notice they isn't a space between the numbers and AM/PM; it is actually a string right now. I can convert it to a time if needed, but would like to keep it as is if possible

Comment: If you use `TimeValue(hours,minutes,seconds)` with the values you'd extract from the string, you'd get a pretty valid date object. To do so, try `myHour = Left(mystring, Len(mystring) - 3)` and `myMinutes = Right(mystring, 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think taht while it would be possible to do with a formula, the formula would be large and unwieldy.  A UDF would be easier to create and maintain.

Try this

```
Function WorkTime(Breaks As Range, Shift As Variant, CurTime As Date) As Variant
    Dim Lunch As Date
    Dim Break1 As Date
    Dim Break2 As Date
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim BreakTime As Long

    With Application
        v = .Match(Shift, Breaks.Columns(1), 0)
        Lunch = .Index(Breaks.Columns(3), v)
        Break1 = .Index(Breaks.Columns(2), v)
        Break2 = .Index(Breaks.Columns(4), v)
    End With

    v = DateDiff("n", CurTime, Lunch)
    Select Case v
        Case -30 To 0
            BreakTime = 30 + v
        Case 0 To 30
            BreakTime = 30 - v
    End Select

    v = DateDiff("n", CurTime, Break1)
    Select Case v
        Case -15 To 0
            BreakTime = BreakTime + 15 + v
        Case 0 To 15
            BreakTime = BreakTime + v
        Case 15 To 30
            BreakTime = BreakTime + 30 - v
    End Select

    v = DateDiff("n", CurTime, Break2)
    Select Case v
        Case -15 To 0
            BreakTime = BreakTime + 15 + v
        Case 0 To 15
            BreakTime = BreakTime + v
        Case 15 To 30
            BreakTime = BreakTime + 30 - v
    End Select

    WorkTime = 1# - BreakTime / 30#
End Function
```

Comment: +1 didn't realise udf could be so extensive...what do # do, are they a shortcut to a numeric type? (...in here  WorkTime = 1# - BreakTime / 30#)

Comment: This worked perfectly, I will add the updated code so that you can see the check I put in in case the time is outside of the range provided (person should be off shift so it should show 0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the responses. This has really helped me save HOURS of work. :)

chris neilsen - Thats exactly what I was looking for. Here is the code I added to check in case the person was off shift. :)

```
Dim WholeShift() As String

WholeShift = Split(Shift, "-")

For i = LBound(WholeShift) To UBound(WholeShift)
    WholeShift(i) = Trim(WholeShift(i))
    If Len(WholeShift(i)) = 3 Then
        WholeShift(i) = 0 & WholeShift(i)
    End If
Next

If DateDiff("n", CDate(Left(WholeShift(0), 2) & ":" & Right(WholeShift(0), 2)), CurTime) > 0 Or DateDiff("n", CDate(Left(WholeShift(1), 2) & ":" & Right(WholeShift(1), 2)), CurTime) <= 0 Then
    CalcShiftCoverage = 0
    Exit Function
End If
```